# "ValueError: The shape of the input to "Flatten" is not fully defined" with variable length LSTM

Tags: python, keras, lstm, text-classification, variable-length

Here's my code:

```
    from keras.layers import LSTM, Bidirectional, Dense, Input, Flatten
    from keras.models import Model

    input = Input(shape=(None, 100))
    lstm_out = Bidirectional(LSTM(10, return_sequences=True))(input)
    something = Flatten()(lstm_out)
    output = Dense(22, activation='softmax')(something)

    model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adadelta', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I'm building an LSTM with variable input through 
[this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189070/how-do-i-create-a-variable-length-input-lstm-in-keras). But now my model is saying `ValueError: The shape of the input to "Flatten" is not fully defined (got (None, 20)`. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't apply `Flatten` if the number of timesteps is `unknown` at graph creation time - how many input units would the last `Dense` layer have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't *fix* this particular problem because you can pass a variable size vector to a `Dense` layer. *Why?* Because it has a fixed size weights matrix, i.e. the kernel `W`.

You should instead look at layers that can handle variable length sequences such as RNNs. For example you can let the LSTM learn a representation over the entire sequence:

```
input = Input(shape=(None, 100))
lstm_out = Bidirectional(LSTM(10))(input) # the LSTM produces a single fixed size vector
output = Dense(22, activation='softmax')(lstm_out) # Dense classifies it
```

If you want more capacity in your model you can chain RNN layers so long as the last one doesn't return sequences:

```
lstm_out = Bidirectional(LSTM(10, return_sequences=True))(input)
lstm_out = Bidirectional(LSTM(10))(lstm_out) # this LSTM produces a single vector
```