# Training a KerasRegressor with LSTM using all sequence outputs and a whole series of targets

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I've got a problem where I'd like to train on multiple time series. I have a multi-dimensional input and a univariate output. The feature I'm trying to predict is not included in the input, so I want features[:now] -> LSTM -> target[now]. I want this for all values of `now` in the series. My series are of varying lengths.

I gather from [Jason Brownlee's posts](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting-long-short-term-memory-network-python/) that input is given as a tensor of shape `(n_samples, n_timesteps, n_features)`, and I've remembered/found that I can deal with different lengths of series [by passing `None` for `n_timesteps` in the model's `input_shape`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189070/how-do-i-create-a-variable-length-input-lstm-in-keras). Great.

But I don't want to have to grab `(features[:i], target[i])` for all `i` and call `fit` over and over and over again, when the network is perfectly primed to take `(features[i+1], target[i+1])` and find gradients right after `i`.

How can I use all my targets efficiently, without having to reset state and refit to tons of different views of my data? Why is [the Keras documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) so bad that it doesn't even specify the dimensionality `x` and `y` are supposed to take?

Comment: Aside: Obviously I want to reset the state between series while training. I've managed to figure out that if examples are passed as a batch, then [`n_samples` different states are held in the LSTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43882796/when-does-keras-reset-an-lstm-state), so they don't interfere. But I don't think I can create a tensor with all my samples without padding, since that becomes one tensor, and my sequences are of variable lengths. But I'm okay with calling `fit()` on each individually, with a batch size of 1.

Comment: Do I need to make my LSTM layer stateful and pass each sequence one point at a time? I can imagine setting up my network to take input of shape `(n_timesteps=1, n_features)` and calling `fit(features[i], target[i])` for each `i`, then resetting state manually at the end. Just seems like there should be a way to do this inside the library call.

Comment: I found what the output dimension is. It's `(n_samples, n_units)`, where the number of units is the number of LSTM nodes in the layer. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcGf_Uo7NMw

Comment: It looks like [return_sequences=True](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/keras/layers/LSTM) would cause the layer to return the thing I want to be comparing my targets against, but I'm not sure what to do from there. ["You may also need to access the sequence of hidden state outputs when predicting a sequence of outputs with a Dense output layer wrapped in a TimeDistributed layer."](https://machinelearningmastery.com/return-sequences-and-return-states-for-lstms-in-keras/) That's intriguing.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have figured it out. I essentially want to do [many-to-many prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43034960/many-to-one-and-many-to-many-lstm-examples-in-keras).

```py
# create LSTM
n_samples = 1 # batches of one sequence at a time
n_timesteps = None # sequences of variable length
n_features = X_train.shape[1] # the width of the input matrix
n_neurons = 10 # number of LSTM nodes

def make_lstm():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(n_neurons, input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features), return_sequences=True))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1))) # single output per timestep
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    print(model.summary())
    return model

estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=make_lstm, epochs=100,
                           batch_size=1, verbose=True)

# reshape data to (1, trial_length, n_features) before passing to the network
# output comes back of shape (1, trial_length)
```